# IDA - Remote debug on linux

Tags: ida, debugging, elf, remote

I am trying to debug remotly an ELF from my windows 10 (the ELF runs on my ubuntu 32 bit vm) (the ELF is from pwnable.kr - unlink).
Because the exploit is via gets() I try to pass input through the "debugger options" in IDA:

[image: The process options]

(I also tried doing it without the "parameters").

anyway this is the the exception I get when I get to "gets" function.

[image: The exception on IDA]

I tried to understand from the internet how people usually use remote debugging with IDA and use the process' stdin.

BTW: this is how it runs:

```
shahar@ubuntu:~/Desktop$ ./linux_server unlink
IDA Linux 32-bit remote debug server(ST) v1.15. Hex-Rays (c) 2004-2012
Listening on port #23946...
=========================================================
[1] Accepting connection from 192.168.188.1...
here is stack address leak: 0xbfdfdc04
here is heap address leak: 0x9085410
now that you have leaks, get shell!
```

Thanks a lot for your help! :-)

***EDIT:***

This is where the error is raised:

[image]

Comment: Set a breakpoint at the main function, then step forward line by line with F8. You may find the code where that error was shown.

Comment: @Biswapriyo Hi! thanks for your answer but I probably did not explain myself well: I started debug it and when I got to the "gets" function I had this error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I usually do is to supply the STDIN data from a file. So, in the command line you used to run the Linux debugging server I would just add the redirection of the file with the inputs for the get, like this:

`$ ./linux_server unlink < your_file`

For some reason, I never got to work the redirection in parameters with remote debuggers.

Comment: It worked! thanks a lot!
summery: my mistake was redirecting on IDA (on debbuger options -> parameters) and not on the shell where I ran the linux_server.

Comment: @ShaharZelig If joxeankoret answer solved your problem mark his answer as accepted answer.